what apps/code would someone use to remote spy on me through the permissions on the camera of /microphone their old android phone?
 android.hardware.camera
android.hardware.camera.any
android.hardware.camera.autofocus
android.hardware.camera.capability.manual_post_processing
android.hardware.camera.capability.manual_sensor
android.hardware.camera.capability.raw
android.hardware.camera.flash
android.hardware.camera.front
android.hardware.camera.level.full
android.hardware.faketouch
android.hardware.fingerprint
android.hardware.location
android.hardware.location.gps
android.hardware.location.network
android.hardware.microphone
android.hardware.screen.landscape

etc
i reset the phone but its been going on 2 weeks they had access remotely

Many apps are available, but many other avenues don't require an app, which you may have inadvertently permitted. In addition, there are next-level spy tactics that can do this kind of thing.
This is not a question for stack overflow; this is a question for your local mobile phone expert who can inspect the device physically.
If you have reset the phone back to factory settings and they can still spy on you, it would be safer to get a new device. Then, a discussion with your local police to reprimand the person stalking you.
